# Как получить Path из картинки?

Tags: android, android-sdk

В одной библиотеке используется Path, он, как я понял, ссылается на картинку. Как декодировать свою картинку в такое представление? В виде:

```
public static final String DROID_LOGO = "M 149.22,22.00\n" +
            "           C 148.23,20.07 146.01,16.51 146.73,14.32\n" +
            "             148.08,10.21 152.36,14.11 153.65,16.06\n" +
            "             153.65,16.06 165.00,37.00 165.00,37.00\n" +
            "             194.29,27.24 210.71,27.24 240.00,37.00\n" +
            "             240.00,37.00 251.35,16.06 251.35,16.06\n" +
            "             252.64,14.11 256.92,10.21 258.27,14.32\n" +
            "             258.99,16.51 256.77,20.08 255.78,22.00\n" +
            "             252.53,28.28 248.44,34.36 246.00,41.00\n" +
            "             252.78,43.16 258.78,48.09 263.96,52.85\n" +
            "             281.36,68.83 289.00,86.62 289.00,110.00\n" +
            "             289.00,110.00 115.00,110.00 115.00,110.00\n" +
            "             115.00,110.00 117.66,91.00 117.66,91.00\n" +
            "             120.91,76.60 130.30,62.72 141.04,52.85\n" +
            "             146.22,48.09 152.22,43.16 159.00,41.00\n" +
            "             159.00,41.00 149.22,22.00 149.22,22.00 Z\n" +
            "           M 70.80,56.00\n" +
            "           C 70.80,56.00 97.60,100.00 97.60,100.00\n" +
            "             101.34,106.21 108.32,116.34 110.21,123.00\n" +
            "             113.76,135.52 103.90,147.92 91.00,147.92\n" +
            "             78.74,147.92 74.44,139.06 69.00,130.00\n" +
            "             69.00,130.00 39.80,82.00 39.80,82.00\n" +
            "             35.73,75.29 28.40,66.08 29.20,58.00\n" +
            "             30.26,47.20 38.61,40.47 49.00,39.72\n" +
            "             61.22,40.24 64.96,46.28 70.80,56.00 Z\n" +
            "           M 375.80,58.00\n" +
            "           C 376.60,66.08 369.27,75.29 365.20,82.00\n" +
            "             365.20,82.00 336.00,130.00 336.00,130.00\n" +
            "             330.71,138.82 326.73,147.24 315.00,147.89\n" +
            "             301.74,148.63 291.14,135.87 294.79,123.00\n" +
            "             296.68,116.34 303.66,106.21 307.40,100.00\n" +
            "             307.40,100.00 333.00,58.00 333.00,58.00\n" +
            "             339.02,47.98 342.23,40.92 355.00,39.72\n" +
            "             365.83,40.00 374.69,46.77 375.80,58.00 Z\n" +
            "           M 289.00,116.00\n" +
            "           C 289.00,116.00 289.00,239.00 289.00,239.00\n" +
            "             288.98,249.72 285.92,257.31 275.00,261.10\n" +
            "             265.22,264.50 258.37,259.56 255.02,264.43\n" +
            "             253.78,266.24 254.00,269.84 254.00,272.00\n" +
            "             254.00,272.00 254.00,298.00 254.00,298.00\n" +
            "             254.00,304.85 254.77,310.07 250.36,315.93\n" +
            "             242.35,326.68 226.84,326.49 218.80,315.93\n" +
            "             215.07,311.00 215.01,306.83 215.00,301.00\n" +
            "             215.00,301.00 215.00,262.00 215.00,262.00\n" +
            "             215.00,262.00 190.00,262.00 190.00,262.00\n" +
            "             190.00,262.00 190.00,301.00 190.00,301.00\n" +
            "             189.99,306.83 189.93,311.00 186.20,315.93\n" +
            "             178.16,326.49 162.65,326.68 154.64,315.93\n" +
            "             151.09,311.22 151.01,307.61 151.00,302.00\n" +
            "             151.00,302.00 151.00,272.00 151.00,272.00\n" +
            "             151.00,269.84 151.22,266.24 149.98,264.43\n" +
            "             146.53,259.42 138.97,264.76 129.00,260.86\n" +
            "             118.39,256.72 116.02,248.29 116.00,238.00\n" +
            "             116.00,238.00 116.00,116.00 116.00,116.00\n" +
            "             116.00,116.00 289.00,116.00 289.00,116.00 Z";
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста в вопрос больше информации. К примеру, какие у вас исходные данные и опишите более подробно какой результат вам нужен.

Comment: я хочу использовать библиотеку
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2605
там есть поле с комментарием "Set Path String"хочу узнать как строить этот Path.

Comment: А у вас какая картинка-то? Растр/вектор?

Comment: @D-side, уже ответили ведь...

Comment: @Qwertiy но что ж поделаешь, если вопрос так и остался неполным.

Comment: @D-side, ну не знаю... Я по строке в вопросе вполне узнаю атрибут `path` из svg.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, но какая картинка у автора есть изначально, неизвестно.

Comment: @D-side, но ведь он принял ответ - его проблема решена. Смысла дополнять вопрос (с его стороны) больше нет. Остальным он вполне понятен. И ответ есть. Так зачем же его закрывать? Если есть желание, можно дополнить самому, но я не вижу и в этом смысла.

Comment: @Qwertiy вопросы не для автора, вопросы для сообщества. Я считаю, что вопрос неполный, я выразил своё мнение голосом за закрытие, снабдил комментарием и пошёл дальше.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот Path и есть картинка, для VectorDrawable, а не путь к файлу как вы наверняка подумали.

Для того чтоб декодировать ваш svg в похожую форму из которой можно было бы получить Path, можно использовать любую библиотеку для этого, вот одна из -> [svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)